# Replace number with last four digits of it

Tags: regex

I want to replace seven or more digits number with the following pattern.

`1234567` to `4567/1234567`

I'm using the following regex for matching the number `(\d*(\d{4}))` and replace it with the `$2/$1`

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to do it with regex and not with whatever codebase you are using like java or c++? Regex is good for finding things, but I wouldn't necessarily use it for replacing and adding things to strings. It just gets messy.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C# but I have lots of number in a string that comes from db. I think it's easy to replace it with regex.

Comment: @KeithEnlow: Is there any reason not to use RegEx, when your language has it? Some years ago I was asked in a Google-interview how to validate IP4 addresses using regex. First I thought it was a trick-question for finding out if I'm performance aware. So I told - "doing this would be nonsense". They taught me otherwise and helped me in Sokrat's manner to create a regexp which could validate all valid IP4 combinations. I've understood the power of RegExps, but there were left no time for other questions, and I've failed the interview. So would probably you :-)

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Fair point haha That would make it a good thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way is `(\d+(\d{4}))` since when you have less than five digits, you don't need to make anything. To be more precise you can use character classes with ranges since you use only ascii digits: `([0-9]+([0-9]{4}))` *(`\d` may indeed contain all kinds of digits like `٢` if `\d` is seen in a unicode meaning)*.

I don't see a better structure for the pattern. But if you have few digits *(less than nine)*, using a non-greedy quantifier may be better:

```
([0-9]+?([0-9]{4}))
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm curious about is there any way to do this with the replace pattern. For ex. If I get the number with  only \d+, could I transform the number with something like that $1{4}/$1

Comment: @ogun: no this kind of things doesn't exist. The possibilities of a replacement string are limited to backreferences. And if the language you use, allows a callback function as replacement, you will finish with a more complicated way.